# Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.2: Tag mismatch

Tags: react-native, android-studio, sdk

This issue arise when I download android studio.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK
package Android SDK Platform 33: Tag mismatch!.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK
package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.2: Tag
mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK
package Android SDK Platform-Tools: Tag mismatch!.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK
package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]